# TYPO3 + YAG show album date in frontend

Tags: date, typo3, frontend, extbase

I'm using TYPO3 v6.2.3 and the YAG - Gallery-Extension.
At my YAG-Backend I can insert a DATE for every album, but this DATE won't be show at my Frontend (Album Overview). Ho can I show the Album-Date (Resources/Private/Templates/Album/List.html) in Frontend?

I have no idea from Extbase-Extensions? Should I change the Ext. or can I show the DATE with TypoScript?

Thanks for your help.

[image: db table, field date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the YAG listview renders a partial to output each listitem, you should add the date to this partial (Resources/Private/Partials/Album/AlbumThumb.html).

```
<f:format.date format="d.m.Y - H:i:s" date="{album.date}"/>
```

This outputs the date of the album in the format given to the date ViewHelper.

Comment: How to change the path to AlbumThumb.html? `plugin.tx_yag.settings.themes.default.albumList.albumThumbPartial = fileadmin/ext/yag_gallery/AlbumThumb.html` didn't work